# Who got a specific hat in Winterbash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

Where can we see the list of members who got a specific hat during Winterbash, like we can see in a specific [badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer)? Is it possible?
If it is, can we filter by country or by specific information?

Comment: You can search the leader boards. I don't think there's a better way.

Comment: @Eran is correct, there is no way, and there's already a feature request asking to let us do this.